# How to add a line at the bottom of a column chart in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How to add a black line at the bottom of a column chart in highcharts as shown in the screenshot.
[column chart with a line at the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVij5.png)

```
Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/agq6ebjd/
```

note:- there is a plot line in the jsfiddle i need to have the plotline and also the black line at the bottom of graph both are needed.

Thanks in advance

updated screenshot post the implementation from the answer.[remove the line outside the grey area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93Vsk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show x-axis without labels and ticks:

```
    xAxis: {
        lineWidth: 2,
        lineColor: '#000',
        tickLength: 0,
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/agq6ebjd/1/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.lineWidth

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.lineColor

Comment: Thanks for the response. I want to get the line at the bottom of column chart only untill the column bars end as in the screen shot.    The plot line extends even further than the bars(columns)  below which I dont need the black line how can I get this behaviour?

Comment: Please check out the "updated screenshot post the implementation from the answer remove the line outside the grey area" UPDATED ABOVE for more clarity on the followup question.

Comment: In this case you can add another x-axis with reduced width. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/8dra01ux/

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply, The width approach decreases the width of the entire x-axis is there a way to only decrease the length of the line and not altering the x-axis width??

Comment: @Nagachandra, but it doesn't matter if you add an extra axis. As a different solution, you can use `Highcharts.SVGRenderer`: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#path

Comment: Thank you for the solution it was very helpful.